# Broadcast receiver is not called when alarm goes off

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm working on the app that will start two alarms as the following:

1. Repeating alarm at every hour once it's started
2. Non-repeating alarm at either 1 to 10 hours based on the user selection

Both of the alarms are using ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP type. The problem I'm facing now is that the same codes work fine on Android 2.3.5 but Android 4.0.4. I have done some research on google and the problem doesn't seem to link to the issue of "no broadcast receiver will be triggered until the app is launched manually for the first time".

The following are the codes for setting up the pending intent for both the alarms:

```
private class AlarmEvent {
    private Intent mIntent;
    private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;

    protected AlarmEvent(Context ctx, Class<?> cls, int pendingIntentType,
                         int requestCode, int flags, String intentAction) {
        mIntent = new Intent(ctx, cls);
        mIntent.setAction(intentAction);

        switch(pendingIntentType) {
        case PENDING_BROADCAST:
            mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, requestCode, mIntent, flags);
            break;
        case PENDING_SERVICE:
            mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ctx, requestCode, mIntent, flags);
            break;
        default:
            Log.w(TAG, "AlarmEvent:Invalid pending intent type=" + pendingIntentType);
        }
    }

    protected PendingIntent getPendingIntent() {
        return mPendingIntent;
    }
}
```

The following are the codes to create the AlarmEvent:

```
    //Create polling event
    mPollingEvent = new AlarmEvent(mCtx, EventRouter.class, PENDING_BROADCAST, 
                POLLING_REQUEST_CODE, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT,
                EventRouter.POLLING_ACTION);
    //Create monitor event
    mReminderEvent = new AlarmEvent(mCtx, EventRouter.class, PENDING_BROADCAST,
                REMINDER_REQUEST_CODE, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT,
                EventRouter.REMINDER_ACTION);
```

The following are the codes to start the alarms:

```
    //Get AlarmManager instance
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)mCtx.getSystemService(AS);
    long triggerAtTime = 0;
    //Process the request
    switch(type) {
    case POLLING:
        triggerAtTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, triggerAtTime, 
                    POLLING_INTERVAL_MS, mPollingEvent.getPendingIntent());
        Log.d(TAG, "alarmRequest:Polling starts at " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        break;
    case REMINDER:
        triggerAtTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + when;
        alarm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, triggerAtTime, mReminderEvent.getPendingIntent());
            Log.d(TAG, "alarmRequest:Reminder to be fired after " + when + " ms");
        break;
    }
```

The following are the codes of the EventRouter:

```
public class EventRouter extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String POLLING_ACTION = "com.xxxxxx.POLLING";
    public static final String REMINDER_ACTION = "com.xxxxxx.REMINDER";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive:Action=" + action);

        if(POLLING_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            //TODO: Polling handling
        }
        else if(REMINDER_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            //TODO: Reminder handling to fire a status bar notification
        }
    }
}
```

The Android manifest for my app:

```
<application 
    ...
    ...>
    <activity
        android:name=".AlarmActivity"
        ...>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".EventRouter" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"/>
</application>
```

Both of the alarms are registered properly by executing the following command on terminal:

```
adb -d shell dumpsys alarm
```

However, only the POLLING alarm is delivered to my receiver. I have been struggling on this issue for a while and could not find a solution. Can you help to review the way I set up my pending intent to see if there is any mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You should add your actions as an intent filter to your receiver declaration in your manifest file so that it can capture those actions.

```
<receiver android:name=".EventRouter" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="your.receiver.package.name.POLLING_ACTION"></action>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="your.receiver.package.name.REMINDER_ACTION"></action>
</intent-filter>

<receiver/>
```

This is the first mistake that caught my eye.

Comment: I think if the intent is passed to the AlarmManager, and the intent is created with a specific component, we can omit the intent filter in the manifest. I'm not very sure about this, but it works for the POLLING alarm.

Comment: You never know without trying.